# Storing Comments in firebase using angularjs

Tags: javascript, database, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Here is a form:

```
<span class="input-label">Name</span>
<input ng-model="name" type="text">
<span class="input-label">Comment</span>
<input ng-model="msg" type="text">
<button ng-click="addMessage()">Comment</button>
```

On firing click event, I call the addMessage() function in the controller:

```
app.controller('CommentCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', function($scope, $firebase){
    var myRootRef = new Firebase("my://app/link");
    $scope.addMessage = function() {
        /*
         * How do I store the name and comment obtained
         * from the form in firebase.
         *
         * set, push does not work at all
        */
        $scope.modal.hide();
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close, just a couple of things.

We need to create an AngularFire binding by passing in a Firebase reference. Since we're using `ng-model` we can grab the properties from `$scope`. However, it's probably a good idea to provide a default value for the name and comment properties.

When we call `addMessage` we need to go to a child location for messages by calling `$child`. Then we can add a new message by calling `$add`.

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/eeOKisDzYWIWxmLEuyvM?p=preview)**

```
app.controller('CommentCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', function($scope, $firebase){
    var myRootRef = new Firebase("my://app/link");
    $scope.messages = $firebase(myRootRef); // AngularFire binding created here

    // default values
    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.msg= '';

    $scope.addMessage = function() {
        // go to the messages location and push the item by calling $add
        $scope.messages.$child('messages').$add({
          name: $scope.name,
          comment: $scope.msg
        });

        // clear out the values after adding them to Firebase
        $scope.msg= '';
        $scope.name = '';

        $scope.modal.hide();
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I tried it. But the values in firebase database is just an empty string

Comment: It is really getting tough.

Comment: Ah, that's because I incorrectly named your comment property on the $scope. It should be msg rather than comment. Since ng-model is set to msg and comment is set to the empty string it will never get updated. So we can change comment to msg. Try it now. Also let me know what you're inputting as values.

Comment: I tried, actually i noticed it the first time, but still empty strings it is. Value are just jibberish for name and comment

Comment: It is still null. dont know why $scope.name is null :(

Comment: I updated my answer with a demo to a working Plunker. You can download that as a zip and try it from there too.

Comment: Hey, the problem was with prototypical inheritance. Solved it now.

Comment: Let me know if my answered work for you. If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.

Comment: Pagination with firebase using FIrebase.util.js?